# inner class file name uses $ and not any other symbol. why?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I was recently asked this question in an interview.

when a class with inner class is compiled there are two class files that are created. eg

```
class A{ class B{}}
```

So in this case 2 class files will be generated. A.class and A$B.class.

Why '$' symbol is used and not any other symbol?
Does this question have a technical answer or is it subjective?

Comment: It is more or less arbitrary.

Comment: Because why not? It could be one of ((*&^%$) or anything else, but $ was chosen.

Comment: @Antoniossss, It cannot be just any symbol.The JLS specifies what characters are legal in an identifier, and most of the ones you mentioned are not. The JLS, which I commend to your attention, says that `$` is used for automatic, under-the-hood names, which is why it's used in generated class names. It's best to Read the Fine Manual.

Comment: @LewBloch But it is all about that it was *chosen*. World would not explode if someone would choose % for that - despite file system restrictions etc etc.

Comment: `%` is not legal for an identifier in Java. See the JLS. It has nothing to do with file systems, "etc etc [sic]". Please read the JLS.